# Not able to accept json as iput in a REST POST request

Tags: java, json, rest

I am writing a REST service for accepting POST calls which will taken JSON as input parameters. The pseudo code I am using is :

```
@POST
@Path("/decodeJson")
//@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String decodeJson(Employee book) throws Exception {
return "hi";
}
```

I have a pojo class for the `Employee`. When I run a POST request, I am getting the following error:

> SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.sampleservice.model.Employee, and Java type class com.sampleservice.model.Employee, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.
>   The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
>   * / * ->

Have any one seen this error? What is the best way to parse JSON in a REST service class? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the suggesstion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by adding the following :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

to the pom.xml and by adding the following to the EMployee pojo class. make sure that the version of the two are same. Also add:
@XmlRootElement
 to the POJO class